# Will the batteries be charged?

Tags: batteries, current, battery-charging, charging

We have three batteries in parallel that need to be charged. They are 100 A each, 300 A in total.

If we connect these batteries to a DC source of 15 V with a maximum load of 3 A, will the batteries be charged or not?

Note that the source wire is thinner than the battery wire. Will it burn or will the higher voltage protect it?

[image: 3 batteries 12 V 100 A in parallel]

Comment: A is the unit of current, Ah a unit of capacity. Are you specifying the batteries' maximum output current, maximum charging current, or capacity?

Comment: The batteries are like car battery so I am specifying the maximum output current,  Ah

Comment: Ah is never the maximum output current. It's the battery's *capacity*. The maximum output current is usually stated as CCA (Cold Cranking Amps) for car batteries. 15V is too high for prolonged charging of lead acid batteries. They will be damaged. If you have to use a fixed voltage, use 13.6-13.8V, but it's better to use a proper battery charger.

Comment: Please edit accordingly.

Comment: When ever you  are dealing with sources (the batteries) that can supply hundreds of amps you need to give consideration to fusing. Your comments about the source wire lead me to suspect you have not. You need to put fuses in the circuit to protect the wiring.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't charge (lead-acid?) batteries like that.

The end voltage will be too high (15 V) and there is nothing that limits the charging current except the batteries' internal resistance and the fuse (or failure) of your DC voltage source.

Why not use a proper battery charger? It will take care of maximum charging voltage and current and have wires that can carry its maximum charging current.

Comment: Let assume that we have the charge controller, and the batteries full charge voltage is 12.7v but the schema is simple for understanding purpose

Comment: If you have a charger, the schematic is too simple for understanding purposes.

Comment: @FraVilsoni But you asked if they can be charged by 15V supply. For that the simple answer is "no, don't even try that". There was no assumption there is a charge controller which fully changes the question and current answers are not based on that information.

Answer (score 3):

Batteries can't be charged by just connecting them to a power supply, as both are voltage sources.

In short, don't even try. Charge batteries with a battery charger.

Trying may just damage the power supply.

The main reason is that two voltage sources can't be connected together.

If you do, the battery tries to keep the common node at 12V by sinking current, and the power supply  tries to keep the common node at 15V by sourcing current.

If both were ideal voltage supplies, it would be a paradox because even if infinite current flows, the node between a 12V and 15V voltage source cannot be simultaneously be at both 12V and 15V.

In practice, what would happen, in some order:

Power supply is limited to 12V and it can't provide the required amps beyond 3A to rise the output back to 15V, so it gets shut down due to overcurrent. It may try to restart a few times per second until you remove the battery.

Power supply may hit 3A safe limit and limit itself to 3A output. But because the output can't rise to 15V, the power supply may have an undervoltage protection and it can shut down. It may try to restart but undervoltage happens until you remove the battery.

Power supply may blow up if it can't handle being connected to another supply, even if the batteries are 12V.

If the power supply does not blow up, it may simply keep restarting forever and while doing so charge the battery a bit every time. It might charge the batteries extremly slowly but it will never stop charging and will keep charging until batteries have 15V and then it will keep the batteries floating at 15V. That's more than the batteries can handle and they get damaged.

Comment: I think that the chargers are not magic things, they simply bring to batteries current with higher voltage. Normally by checking the voltage of the batteries until they are fully charged.

Comment: @FraVilsoni It's not magic to limit the current, and stop charging when the battery voltage gets too high. That's something that battery chargers do, and your 15 V power supply doesn't. Don't do what your diagram shows. If you add extra components, or information about how the supply deals with too high a load, or check the voltage from time to time manually, then maybe it would be OK. The devil is always in the detail.

Comment: @FraVilsoni Exactly, and that is why you need a charger to charge batteries and why power supplies can't charge batteries. To some the difference is magical. They also think the mains adapters for mobile phones or laptops are the charger, but it isn't. They are power supplies for the charging circuitry that is inside the phone or laptop.